# Hover/Link state is only triggered on certain areas of link

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

The problem I am having is that when you mouse over the button, only certain parts of it will trigger the hover/clickable state, not all of the actual block. Any ideas why?

Here is the site where it is being used: http://www.revival.tv/turningpoint/#about-wrap

Here is the css

```
#facebook, #twitter {
float: left;
display: block;
height: 25px;
width: 65px;
color:#fff;
line-height: 25px;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 7px;
border-radius:7px;
cursor: pointer;
opacity:1;
background-color: #DA178D;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#DA178D), to(#c3147d));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DA178D, #c3147d);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #DA178D, #c3147d);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #DA178D, #c3147d);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #DA178D, #c3147d);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DA178D, #c3147d);
}
#facebook:hover, #twitter:hover {
opacity:.7;
}
```

Comment: is its height and width 100% of its parent? i had a problem like that

Comment: it does seem to be the float left. I tried adding the float to the link itself with no luck. Any ideas why a float would cause this? When I remove the float from the counter, they work fine. But, I need that to be floated as well.

Comment: removing the float worked because it moved the `:before` spacing out of the way of the link.

Comment: Yeah.. moving the `:before` to be an `:after` on `#facebook` and `#twitter` seemed to do it. A little unhappy about it as you got some weird percentage positioning, perhaps consider using exact pixels. And of course some browser checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that div `#fbcount.count` has more z-index than your `a#facebook` and your div `#twcount.count` has more z-index than `a#twitter`. Adjust them to go below their respective links(decrease their z-index to a lesser value than the links). As of now, the hover event is registered by the div's and not the links when the mouse hovers over them.

Comment: Added position relative and z-index of 5 to both with no luck.

Comment: And what is the z-index of the links?

Comment: Give  #fbcount.count and #twcount.count, z-index 4

Comment: I'm sorry, you were correct with the z-index. I was in a hurry when adding it to it, and for some reason thought something else was getting in the way, not those two interfering with each other. This worked perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `:before` selector on `.count` with the left positioning of -100% that's the culprit. `:before` selectors don't work in IE anyway (if you care).

An alternative solution would be make a separate DIV for the triangles, have them floated left as well so that they line up perfectly.

EDIT: Aha... the `:before` pseudoelement inherits the properties of parent, in this case `.count`. So that little triangle actually has a width of 35px.

**SOLUTION**: A tad bit hacky... but I moved the `:before` on `.count` to be a `:after` on `#facebook` and `#twitter`. A little positioning and it seems to work. To vertically align the text, you can set the `line-height` to be the same as the `height`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XmYwe/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I knew it had to be something.

Comment: glad to be of help! That was a fun one

Comment: Thanks again for your solution. Ashwin's method above worked better for my situation, it allowed the counter to all be one piece without being somewhat hacky. I appreciate your help though!